# Saving current service name and id to a servicebooking model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I wonder if someone could point me in the right direction. I have service and servicebooking models. My servicebooking table has fields: id, service_name, service_id, date, time and user_id. I have a 'book service' link on my service view page and when saving the booking I want to save the current service name and id to the servicebookings table and the current user id.

Below is my service controllers create action, but I'm not sure how to go about this, I know I need to access the service id and name parameters maybe through hidden fields etc, can any help here? Thanks for your help.

Service has many servicebooking and users have many service and servicebooking.
Service and servicebooking belong to user.

```
def create
    @servicebooking = current_user.servicebookings.build(params[:servicebooking].permit(:service_id, :date, :time, :user_id))
    @servicebooking = //Need some help here

    if @servicebooking.save
      redirect_to @servicebooking
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

//////EDIT - My Services show view

```
<h2><%= @service.name %></h2><%= link_to 'Book this service', new_servicebooking_path %>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @service.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Date Available:</strong>
  <%= @service.date_available %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Time Available:</strong>
  <%= @service.time_available %>
</p>
```

//////EDIT2 My Services edit view

```
<%= form_for @servicebooking, :html => {  :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @servicebooking.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@servicebooking.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this service booking from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @servicebooking.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>



  <p>
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :date %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :time %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :time %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't show your view so it is not easy to propose you how to pass hidden_field like

```
#somewhere in form 
<%= hidden_field_tag 'servicebooking[service_id]', @service.try(:id)  %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'servicebooking[service_name]', @service.try(:name)  %>
```

so i can propose you another approach - `after_validation` hook in Servicebooking model

```
 belongs_to :service #i hope you have this row?
 #...
 after_validation :set_service_name

 def set_service_name
  self.service_name = service.try(:name)
 end
```

`service_id` can (has to) be set through `belongs_to` association or you can add it to method above

**UPDATE**

assuming you have in `Service` model

```
has_many :servicebookings
```

1 from service show view you need to pass `:service_id` param with `new_servicebooking_path`

```
<%= link_to 'Book this service', new_servicebooking_path(service_id: @service.id) %>
```

2 define `@service` variable in controller's `new` method

```
 def new
   @service = Service.find(params[:service_id])
   @servicebooking = @service.servicebookings.new
 end
```

3 insert into edit form this two rows

```
<%= f.hidden_field :service_name, @service.try(:name)  %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.try(:id)  %>
```

or you can even pass `@service.name` and `current_user.id` on controller level (in method new) without any form modifications

```
@servicebooking = @service.servicebookings.new(service_name: @service.try(:name), user_id: current_user.try(:id))
```

Comment: Hey okliv I have updated my question with my services show view

Comment: `...  when saving the booking ...` - you have to show edit form not show view

Comment: Hey Okliv, I have updated with my services edit view